# mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it. - Mac BigSur OS

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Always when i run sql it is asking permission. After setting permission and tried to run mysql server am getting bellow error.

```
2021-09-23T05:16:47.537620Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-09-23T05:16:47.537986Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2021-09-23T05:16:47.538031Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.35) starting as process 9406 ...
2021-09-23T05:16:47.540982Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2021-09-23T05:16:47.542342Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-09-23T05:16:47.542363Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-09-23T05:16:47.542387Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-09-23T05:16:47.542396Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-09-23T05:16:47.542645Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-09-23T05:16:47.542750Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-09-23T05:16:47.544470Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-09-23T05:16:47.552942Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-09-23T05:16:47.570938Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.575457Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-09-23T05:16:47.575798Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-09-23T05:16:47.582647Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.583503Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.583525Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.583714Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-09-23T05:16:47.636229Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.35 started; log sequence number 1237124
2021-09-23T05:16:47.636859Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.637096Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2021-09-23T05:16:47.637210Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.637528Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210923 10:46:47
2021-09-23T05:16:47.638519Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.641260Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.641286Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.641299Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.641310Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.642743Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.642870Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.648162Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2021-09-23T05:16:47.648274Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.648304Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2021-09-23T05:16:47.648393Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.649449Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/usr/local/var' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.649929Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2021-09-23T05:16:47.650368Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2021-09-23T05:16:47.650404Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Failed to initialize ACL/grant/time zones structures or failed to remove temporary table files.
2021-09-23T05:16:47.650787Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Am getting this error continuously. Need help to resolve this.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL - please correct your tags.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: I uninstalled and removed all references. and installed it again, then it got resolved.